# TextBox.SelectAll() funciona quando for através do teclado, quando simulo não

Tags: c#, wpf

Boas pessoal,

Tenho um metodo para 3 TextBox para correr quando ganham focus:

```
private void NumericKeyboardTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    this.textBoxForNumeric = sender as TextBox;
    this.textBoxForNumericFirstTime = true;
    this.textBoxForNumeric.Focus();
    this.textBoxForNumeric.SelectAll();
}
```

Ao por um point break ele para lá seja o enter dado pelo teclado ou pela simulação. Quando é pelo teclado ele selecciona sempre tudo o que está dentro da TextBox, quando é pela simulação da `Key.Enter` passa pelo metodo em cima mas não faz o `SelectAll();`

Aqui fica como estou a simular a key enter (que é de um teclado numero que fiz em WPF)

```
Keyboard.FocusedElement.RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(this.textBoxForNumeric), 0, Key.Enter)
{
    RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyUpEvent
});
```

Ao carregar no botão enter no teclado que fiz, ele passa no metodo mas não faz o `SelectAll` a `TextBox`

O que poderá estar mal aqui ?

Edit.

Adicionado os events para o KeyUp

```
#region Events for KeyUp for the TextBoxPrice & TextBoxNewQtd
private void textBoxBarCodToSearch_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBoxBarCodToSearch.Text))
        {
            FindProdForEventsDataGridAllProds(this.textBoxBarCodToSearch.Text);
        }
    }
}

private void textBoxPrice_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        this.textBoxNewQtd.Focus();
    }
}

private void textBoxNewQtd_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        BindingExpression binding = this.textBoxNewQtd.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        binding.UpdateSource();
        AddNewProdToDoc();
    }
}
#endregion
```

Edit 2:

Era assim que inicialmente estava o metodo `NumericKeyboardTextBox_GotFocus`

```
private void NumericKeyboardTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Passar para a variavel para saber qual o texto a modificar com o teclado virtual criado na WPF
    // As 2 linhas abaixo é como tinha inicialmente, o resto foi adicionado/removido para ver se resolvia o problema
    this.textBoxForNumeric = sender as TextBox;
    (sender as TextBox).SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: Após a chamada ao método `textBoxForNumeric.Focus()`, verifique a propriedade `textBoxForNumeric.IsKeyboardFocusWithin`, se o valor dela for `false`, coloque uma chamada para o método `Keyboard.Focus(textBoxForNumeric)` no seu simulador de pressionamento da tecla <ENTER> e veja se muda alguma coisa.

Comment: Essa propriedade está a `true`

Comment: Como está o código desse evento `KeyUp` que você está roteando, quando a tecla <ENTER> é pressionada? Pode acrescenta-lo à pergunta?

Comment: Adicionado, se puser um point break nos eventos que adicionei, se dou o enter pelo teclado ou pelo botão do teclado numerico que criei, irá sempre lá parar

Comment: Vendo o resto do código agora que me dei conta: Por que você chama o método `textBoxForNumeric.Focus()` dentro do evento `GotFocus` do controle `textBoxForNumeric`? É redundante, se esse evento foi disparado significa que o controle já tem o foco, e aí seria simplesmente selecionar o texto, não?

Comment: So puz porque vi algures, visto que sinceramente não sei mesmo o que se passa aqui, e foi apenas para testar e depois não tirei, que apenas estava a passar para a variavel e a fazer `SelectAll()`, e dentro do `textBoxForNumeric` é apenas para saber qual das 3 é que vai o texto posto no teclado criado na WPF, dai não ter um evento para ver se recebeu focus ou não. Tido isto, antes não estava a fazer `textBoxForNumeric.Focus();` antes e mesmo assim não funcionava

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84599/discussion-between-camadas-and-pedro-gaspar).